# Fatal error: Call to undefined function apply_filters() in /public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 317

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to update my wordpress installation using auto update feature. After update the entire site is down. Checking the log file I have this error:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function apply_filters() in /public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 317`
I found this github issue. But they refer to solving the issue for installation that uses `wp-cli`. Any help would be appreciated.
https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/2953

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This problem was caused by the `wp-settings.php`. Due to permissions trouble this file was not updated while using auto-update. Replacing this file with the latest `wp-settings.php` solved the trouble.

Comment: Yeah, but then you're left with "error establishing database connection"

Answer (score 0):

i just add and use this line to my plugin file

require_once( dirname(**FILE**) . '/../../../../wp-includes/plugin.php');